# Updating state as a nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this type of state in my app

```
state = {
  abc: true,
  array: [
    { id: 12345, done: false },
    { id: 10203, done: false },
    { id: 54321, done: false }
  ]
};
```

I am looking for a solution to the following problem: I need to change done property accordingly to passed id like in the following function when something like this `handle(12345)` is passed as an argument to handle function :

```
  handle = id => {
  this.state.array.map(e => {
    if (e.key === id) {
      this.setState({array: [
        { id: id, done: true },
        { id: 10203, done: false },
        { id: 54321, done: false }
      ]})
    }
  });
};
```

In simple words I need to change just one object in array based on provided id.

Thanks for any help or tips!

Comment: https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [Redux pattern](https://hackernoon.com/redux-patterns-add-edit-remove-objects-in-an-array-6ee70cab2456) to return a new array with the element in question being changed, while keeping your array immutable:

```
handle = id => {
  const updatedArray = this.state.array.map(e => {
    if (e.key === id) {
      return { id: id, done: true };
    }
    else {
      return e;
    }
  });
  this.setState({array: updatedArray});
};
```

This keeps your data structures immutable while changing only what you need to change.

Answer (score 4):

I'd write the `handle` method as:

```
handle = id => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const { array } = prevState;
    return {
      array: [
        ...array.filter(o => o.id !== id),
        {id, done: true}
      ]
    };
  });
};
```

The idea here is that, remove the matching `id` from old state, and then add a new object to the `array` with `id` and `done` property as `{id, done: true}`.

Comment: This also changes the order of the array elements though

Answer (score 3):

Once you are allowed to restructure `state` to be hashmap instead of array:

```
state = {
  abc: true,
  array: {
    12345: { done: false },
    10203: { done: false },
    54321: { done: false }
  ]
};
```

then you will be able to use power of spread operator:

```
let id = 12345;
this.setState({
    array: {
        ...this.state.array,
        [id]: {
            ...this.state.array[id], 
            done: true
        }
    }
});
```

Otherwise using `array.map()` seems to be the only option

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = this.state.array;
  for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
      if(newArray[i].id === 12345) {
        newArray[i].done = true;
      }
  }

  this.setState({array: newArray});
```

By creating the `newArray` here you will be avoiding directly touching the state element, so you can change anything you want inside it afterwards you can set the state.

Comment: Are you still using `for` loop ? :)

Comment: Hi @ArupRakshit I wanted to simplify it for our friend, since the question he was asking is rather simple, so I assumed there is a possibility he is a beginner, this way it'd be easier for him to understand. Fortunately I am not here to boast about my skills or undermine others. Have a good day.